# Use different address after every 20 requests

Tags: security, metasploit

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 to run a pentest on a client's website using `metasploit`'s HTTP scanner module.

After 20 requests, the server I'm testing against blocks my IP and prevents me from being able to continue my brute-force test. As I'm on somewhat of a time crunch, this is a rather annoying issue.

Is there a way to instruct my system to forge the source IP address (say, every 5 requests) of the packets so that I can continue my test and bypass the blocker? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: Who is your employer, and what is the target ?

Comment: A startup utopeen in newdelhi.Employer is MR.Kusum from delhi itself.She got her sites attacked a number of times previously.thats why i don't want even a single chance to make it happen again.First i  have to find every vunerability then only i can advance to fix it.

Comment: I am working as a freelancer for her.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. What you're asking for is *literally impossible* (for all sane intents and purposes, assuming normal resources).

Due to the TCP protocol (which HTTP, and by proxy `metasploit`, uses), changing the source IP address will make it *impossible* for the server to send HTTP status messages back to you.

Therefore, even if you do change the source IP address, it'll be completely useless to you. The server will not be able to tell you anything at all, and there is no way to fix this particular problem short of re-inventing TCP and/or HTTP.

If you're really employed by someone as a freelance pentester, you can contact the standing sysadmin to whitelist your testing IP address.

But, from a cybersecurity person's perspective, let's dig a bit further because why not.

- **Brute-Forcing is a terrible way to test security**
  If you're testing security by guessing literally any password possible, you're just wasting everyone's time. Pentesting and vulnerability detection is about finding problems in the code that allows you to bypass authentication or otherwise mess with the system. Nobody is realistically going to brute-force most systems.
- **If you can't brute-force it, it's secure that way!**
  See point 1. In fact, you can check "can passwords be brute-forced" off your check list entirely. If the system is blocking users after 20 failed attempts, that's good. It's reasonably secure there. Nobody is going to be able to guess a password in 20 tries (unless the password is *really bad*).
- **If you can verify a forged-source bruteforce, you're looking in the wrong place**
  Once again, an extension of point #1. If you're just looking for successful logins in the log (which you can), you have access to the system. And, therefore, you can check actual threats instead of a threat that's both never going to be realistically exploited and is already patched (see #2).

My advice: don't try to forge source IP. Find something else that's a security risk. Like handing out security credentials to a random person over the internet for the purpose of pentesting.

I mean, sure, a persistent attacker *could* use Tor/a large number of proxy servers, but that's a huge waste of the attacker's resources (see #1, again) due to the fact that HTTP brute-forcing is *slow*. You need to generate a POST to the HTTP server, wait for it to calculate and build a web page, return that webpage to you, and then process that web page. It's nothing like attacking a known hash that you have locally, where you can test thousands of values per second.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a good time to invest in a WAF too.